# bower js file keep missing after grunt complie

Tags: javascript, compilation, gruntjs, yeoman

make web app with yeoman

I installed 'angular-loading-bar' with this code

```
bower install angular-loading-bar
```

and add path of this js file in app/index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-loading-bar/build/loading-bar.min.js"></script>
```

it looks work perfectly.

BUT everytime grunt compile, added path in index.html gone..
i tried both  section and

and i checked grunt:dist, it seems like that js file is not included in scripts/vendor.xxxxx.js

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the component with

```
bower install angular-loading-bar --save
```

Comment: thanks, but i got a another problem.. it gave me 'Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$qProvider <- $$q <- $animate <- $compile' on console log

Comment: This sounds more like 1. the order you're loading your plugins is not correct or 2. you defined your modules wrong when doing a directive, service for it.